# Events in TinyMCE fullscreen mode

Tags: tinymce

I have a TinyMCE editor instance with a function tied to the onChange event.
The onChange is bound in the setup section when initializing the editor.

When the editor is in fullscreen mode the function isn't tied to the onChange event in the new fullscreen editor.

Any ideas of how to bind to events in the fullscreen editor?

Comment: How are you registering the change event handler? I tried to use the older "onchange_callback" method and that appeared to work both in the editor and in fullscreen.

Comment: I was doing setup:function(ed){ed.onChange.add(someFunc)}. Using onchange_callback does seem to work in both. Want to write that up as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the recommended method for adding an OnChange event handler is to use the ed.onChange.add() method, if you use the older [onchange_callback](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:onchange_callback) config setting to define the handler, it is fired in both the normal and fullscreen view.